# Is it possible to measure the momentum components at same time in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

It is well known that the components of momentum in quantum mechanichs commute, like this $$ [P_x,P_y] = 0 $$

Basically, it means that the momentum components can be measured independently.

Since I read this, I've been trying to figure it out how an experiment to measure this components at the same time would work and I did not find the answer anywhere. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to measure the momentum vector (magnitude and direction), which includes the various components, no matter your lab coordinates. One example of such a measurement is angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy (ARPES), which measures the momentum of a photo-emitted electron from a material under illumination.